# Android emulator can no longer connect to localhost

Tags: android, networking, localhost, emulation

I have a server on my computer running on `localhost:8080`, previously I was able to access this in the Android emulator under `10.0.2.2:8080` and it worked great. I went to load it again at some point today and it no longer works. No configuration has changed to my knowledge.

I can still access localhost when I use a browser on my computer, so the server is still running okay. But on the emulator, whether using my app or a browser it will not connect.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this in a search, this is how I fixed the problem:

1. Open terminal and enter `sudo nano /private/etc/hosts`
2. Delete the line `::1     localhost`
3. Ctrl-O then enter to save. Ctrl-X to exit.

Restarted my local server and after that it worked.